# Create hotspot without password

Tags: windows, hotspot

Is it possible to create hotspot without the password?

I already tried to create it by `netsh` command and in settings, but I always must enter any password.

Answer (score 2):

- Open command prompt (in Admin mode)
- `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=anything key=`
- `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
- Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center
- Right Click Connection > Properties > Sharing > Allow other users to connect

This should get you where you need to go :)

With the `key` attribute in step 2 - leave it blank.

It goes without saying that there are considerable risks with leaving a blank password - anyone can connect and do anything on your connection - including try to break into your PC.  That said, your question was very specific - so I'll skip the lecture on security and assume you've thought this through and definitely want to take this risk and accept the possible consequences.

Enjoy!

Comment: Edit the answer to include a pre-requisite check to ensure the wireless adapter is capable of being used as a hosted network: `netsh wlan show drivers` - `Hosted network supported` property.

Comment: Yes my wireless adapter is supporting hosted network, but every time when I'm creating it (with blank key parameter too), my new hotspot is locked by some password..